# How to break long strings into paragraphs

Tags: java

I have a String of length 1000-1500 chars. I want to divide the same into paragraphs. What I am doing now is:

```
String tempDisplayText =
    "this is the long...... string of length 1000-2000 chars";
String displayText = null;
if (tempDisplayText != null && tempDisplayText.length() > 400) {
    int firstFullStopIndex = tempDisplayText.indexOf(". ", 350);
    if (firstFullStopIndex > 0) {
        displayText = "<p>"
                + tempDisplayText.substring(0, firstFullStopIndex)
                + ".</p><p>"
                + tempDisplayText.substring(firstFullStopIndex + 1)
                + "</p>";
        feed.setDisplayText(displayText);
    }
}
```

This code is working fine, but divides the whole string into 2 paragraphs only. But some time the next paragraph is too lengthy thus looses its readability. Is there any standard way to divide strings into paragraphs in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why you shouldn't repeat this for the remainder, i.e., the second paragraph. You can't split a sentence.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (tempDisplayText != null) {
    int firstFullStopIndex;
    while( tempDisplayText.length() > 400
       && 
       (firstFullStopIndex = tempDisplayText.indexOf(". ", 350)) >= 0 ){
    sb.append( "<p>" );
    sb.append( tempDisplayText.substring(0, firstFullStopIndex) );
    sb.append( ".</p>" );
    tempDisplayText = tempDisplayText.substring(firstFullStopIndex + 1);
    }
    if( tempDisplayText.length() > 0 ){
        sb.append( "<p>" ).append( tempDisplayText ).append( "</p>" );
    }
    tempDisplayText = sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked exactly.. only one small change I made is : the last .<p> is replaced by <p>, otherwise I am getting .. at the end of the documnet.Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry - copy-paste, as usual :-\